# Show function is continuous using sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

Consider the function g: $R$ $ \rightarrow $ $R$ defined by 
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}2x & x\text{ is rational}\\
-2x & x\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$$

How would I prove $g$ is continuous at $a=0$ using sequences? I know how to do it using limit definition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|g(x_{n}) - 0| = |g(x_{n})| = 2|x_{n}| \to 0$ if $x_{n} \to 0$.

Comment: wonderful tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence which converges to $0$.

take $\epsilon>0.$

there exists $N\in\mathbb N $ suh that

$$n>N\implies |x_n|<\frac {\epsilon}{2} $$

thus for $n>N $,

if $x_n $ is rational then
$$|f (x_n)|=|2x_n|<\epsilon $$
and if $x_n $ is irrational, then
$$|f (x_n)|=|-2x_n|<\epsilon $$

this proves that the sequence $(f (x_n)) $ converges to the limit zero $=f (0) $.